# Is this solution to CTCI's string permutation solution correct?

Tags: java, string

It seems to work, and I can't find anyone else with a similar answer. It's so straightforward- im skeptical.

```
public static boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
    if (s.length() != t.length()) return false; // Permutations must be same length

    int sum = 0;

    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
        sum += c - 'a';

    for(char c : t.toCharArray())
        sum -= c - 'a';

    return sum == 0;
}
```

Also, the time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(1), right??

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't make your decision because of the sum because if you try this `permutation("CTCI", "CCCZ")` will get `true` because of the same sum

you can check this one if you want an algorithm in `O(N)`

```
   public static boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length())
            return false;

        int[] freq = new int[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            freq[s.charAt(i) % 26]++;
            freq[t.charAt(i) % 26]--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
            if (freq[i] != 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Also, wouldnt your solution require the strings to be sorted- meaning O(nlog(n)) time?

Comment: why sorting, just moving and check every character, the complexity is `linear`

Comment: because the question is giving us two strings, where they could be out of order, and if theyre out of order but with the same characters composing them this returns false, when true is the solution. Like "race" and "earc" would return true because we can rearrange earc to be race, but in your solution we cant do that. Either we have to sort the strings before we do your solution, or you can create a count array and see if the count of each character is an even number (and we can allow one character to have a odd count)

Comment: its almost correct: you have to also return true if only ONE bit is a one- ie it could be the middle of the string.